# HTTPS and Data Integrity

Tags: https, integrity

I haven't done lot of research on HTTPS yet so I have a question about it.

Is data integrity preserved using HTTPS or only confidentiality? For example on file upload, does HTTPS guarantee that no one can change the data on upload, or it only guarantees that no one can read it?

Comment: I think this question was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655516/does-encryption-guarantee-integrity

Comment: @kojiro: The two are related, but I think might merit having two separate questions given that this one is specific to HTTPS.

Comment: @kojiro: Also the answer in the linked question is the exact opposite of what is answered to this one.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: **Yes**

Requirements:

- The cipher suite uses a digest algorithm like SHA, SHA-2 (256 or 394) or MD5 (please avoid it !) to compute a Hash-based Message Authentication Code ([HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)). This message is then used to check data integrity for each record.

Example: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_**SHA256**

- The cipher suite supports *Authenticated Encryption with Additional Data* ([AEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AEAD)) like AES-GCM (AES-CCM, AES-EAX exist but are less common) or CHACHA20-POLY1305 (recommended).

Example: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_**CHACHA20_POLY1305**_SHA256

Regarding the second example, it is important to note that SHA256 is NOT the HMAC algorithm but it is used as PRF (check [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/39596/102630) for more details).

Answer (score -2):

For the most part yes, but for maximum security, I would recommend in addition to using HTTPS, I would recommend configuring your server's SSL configuration to use a signed certificate and use the following SSL configurations:

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT
```

Also, use SSL Version 3 if possible.

Comment: +1, good answer.  I deleted mine and hang my head in shame.  ;-)

Comment: I need this for some kind of key management system (private keys would be stored on a server), so that's why I'm asking this. Do you think that should be safe enough for that? Thanks!

Comment: I would highly recommend using the SSL method I mentioned above, if you use that, you should be good to go and safe.

Comment: From reading the answer, I am not sure which part of the proposed configuration guarantees data integrity. @Eli: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Here are some resources that explain SSL/mod_SSL ability to protect both confidentiality and integrity: http://www.mpipks-dresden.mpg.de/~mueller/docs/suse10.1/suselinux-manual_en/manual/sec.apache2.ssl.html http://www.modssl.org/docs/ossc1999/ossctutor.pdf  (The configuration that I included in my above post simply further strengthen the SSL connection.

Comment: This configuration (for Apache) is obsolete and will restrict you to TLS 1.0 which is deprecated.